# When can the isomorphism theorem for Groups be rewritten as a direct product?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\phi:G\to H$ be a homomorphism of groups. 
Under what conditions does 
$\frac{G}{ker (\phi)} \simeq im(\phi)$ imply there exists an isomorphism
$G\simeq im(\phi) \oplus ker(\phi)$, and why?

The answers in the possible duplicate question are not sufficient for me, as I do not have an understanding of category theory or exact sequences. I'm looking for a detailed answer that makes use of basic group theory alone. 
In particular I am interested in knowing if $G$ or $H$ being abelian makes any difference.

Comment: I have looked at the answers to the similar questions mentioned, but I do not understand the answers. Need an answer that does not refer to exact sequences or category theory.

Comment: $G$ or $H$ being abelian doesn't help.

Comment: There is no need to learn about category theory, but you definitely need to learn about exact sequences.